Github actions, rerun maven with log4j on debug?
I have a GitHub-Actions job which generates a huge amount of logging when running test and log-level=debug.
I want to run this test with log-level=WARN, and if it failes, I'd like to re-run the job (or the failed tests) with log-level=DEBUG, preferably by checking the debug-logging checkbox

How do I set this up?

Which "debug-logging checkbox" do you mean?

@Bademeister see updated question

$RUNNER_DEBUG has the value 1 if set the checkbox. You could evaluate this and then set the DEBUG level accordingly. I would try that now. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables

You can use manual workflow triggering with inputs. Try this workflow:
name: Rerun with Debug

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        type: choice
        description: Chose log level
        options:
          - info
          - debug

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ inputs.logLevel }}

Click on the workflow name in the Workflow panel on the left.
Then click "Run workflow" button on the right.
Choose the logging level and run
